# Bulk renaming/updating storage blob files

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

One of our depts named their files "XXX.pdf" while the documents were already  pdfs (1000+). It is causing errors on one of our resource libraries because the files have .pdf.pdf. I am look to see if there is an easy way to bulk rename/update the files to remove .pdf from all of the file names. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  The -whatif makes it harmless.

```
get-childitem *.pdf | rename-item -newname { ($_.BaseName -replace 'pdf') + '.pdf' } -whatif
```